# Java and "generic" interfaces

Tags: java, generics, service, web, interface

I soon need to implement an interface. The interface will need to provide a contract between a web service and 'n' other web services for highway traffic control. The company plans to investigate/test with a single traffic control service at first and add more later as they become available. I can define an interface that's "generic" for this single use case, but the problem is that at any point in the future, we might want to communicate with another web service that may or may not be compatible with the interface we have at that time.

I *could* modify the Java interface as we go to accommodate the differences in API's from third party services. This would also mean updating all implementors of the interface, too.

I would like to know if there are any patterns that would be suitable for this. Almost like "dynamically extending an interface" at run time. Or, any clever use of Java generics that would allow us to implement a single Java interface once that could be used with any/all traffic control systems.

Bottom line: When we come to communicate with any other third party services, I want as minimal effort on our side to integrate them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. It's not like you have a specific problem with your interface. You don't give us a hint as to what it could look like. You're asking about potential new service providers that do not even exist yet. You didn't explain what you mean by an interface (the objects representing the message, the Java client, etc.). Finally, you don't mention the type of services you're planning on using. Big web services? RESTful web services?

Comment: I understand it's vague, but those are the requirements I have. Our web application will call upon a factory to receive an implantation of an interface. That implementation will consume unknown services. I'm wondering if there is any Java/interface magic we can use to lighten the burden of integrating the unknown services later down the line. For example, a third party service might require 1..* request/responses before we get the data we need. Each request might have 1..* parameters. I know it's vague and I suspect the answer is no, but wanted to at least ask anyways.

Comment: You can't solve vague, undefined requirements with extra layers of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is adapting different representations for the same semantics, then define your own interface containing all the semantics you need, and create an adapter layer that transforms the custom representations to yours. This is the same principle behind device drivers.  A uniform client interface and multiple adapters to different devices.

If you expect to encounter "devices" (traffic control services) with wildly differing semantics, then you will have to have multiple driver types... again, exactly the same situation as the difference between block devices and character devices.

Your situation is just another example of a very well known and solved pattern :-)

Comment: Put on hold as too broad?? Obviously not as I now have a lead on something... Device drivers. Thankyou for answering so quickly, Jim!

Comment: I've been doing software since mainframe days (1975) and am amazed at how it's really the same few dozen conceptual problems over and over again.  Most of the "new" paradigms have been around for a long time (virtual machines were being done in the 1960's, for instance).

Comment: Point taken, path accepted. Thanks again, Jim